# Within-week operation on a pandas DataFrame indexed by datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe, apply

I want to get the most frequent value in each week from every column of a `DataFrame` indexed by `datetime`. I know this can be done when entries of the `DataFrame` are all `int` or `float`. But I am looking for a general method that does not take advantage of the data type being `int` or `float`.

Here is an example, where each entry in the `DataFrame` is a `tuple`:

```
2015-11-15 00:00:00   (3, 10.0, 0)   nan
2015-11-16 00:00:00   nan            nan
2015-11-17 00:00:00   nan            nan
2015-11-18 00:00:00   (3, 10.0, 0)   nan
2015-11-19 00:00:00   (3, 10.0, 0)   nan
2015-11-20 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    nan
2015-11-21 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    nan
2015-11-22 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    (1, 1.4, 1)
2015-11-23 00:00:00   (3, 18.0, 1)   (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-11-26 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    (1, 1.4, 1)
2015-11-27 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-11-28 00:00:00   nan            (1, 1.4, 1)
2015-11-29 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-11-30 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    (1, 1.4, 1)
```

This should be transformed into a `DataFrame` consisting of the within-week most frequent tuple as follows:

```
2015-11-15 00:00:00   (3, 10.0, 0)   nan
2015-11-22 00:00:00   (4, 8.2, 0)    (1, 1.4, 1)
```

My preference is for efficiency, speed really matters in my application.

**EDIT**

```
           3046920017503 3046920017541
index                                 
2015-11-15           NaN           NaN
2015-11-16           NaN           NaN
2015-11-17           NaN           NaN
2015-11-18           NaN           NaN
2015-11-19           NaN           NaN
2015-11-20           NaN           NaN
2015-11-21           NaN           NaN
2015-11-22           NaN           NaN
2015-11-23           NaN           NaN
2015-11-24           NaN           NaN
2015-11-25           NaN           NaN
2015-11-26           NaN           NaN
2015-11-27           NaN           NaN
2015-11-28           NaN           NaN
2015-11-29           NaN           NaN
2015-11-30           NaN           NaN
2015-12-01  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-12-02  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-12-03  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-12-04  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-12-05  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-12-06  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
```

should be transformed into:

```
2015-11-15           NaN           NaN
2015-11-22           NaN           NaN
2015-11-29           (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
```

but the method suggested yields:

```
           3046920017503 3046920017541
index                                 
2015-12-05  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-12-12  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is my dataframe `df`

```
                     One           Two
Date                                  
2015-11-15  (3, 10.0, 0)           NaN
2015-11-16           NaN           NaN
2015-11-17           NaN           NaN
2015-11-18  (3, 10.0, 0)           NaN
2015-11-19  (3, 10.0, 0)           NaN
2015-11-20   (4, 8.2, 0)           NaN
2015-11-21   (4, 8.2, 0)           NaN
2015-11-22   (4, 8.2, 0)   (1, 1.4, 1)
2015-11-23  (3, 18.0, 1)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-11-26   (4, 8.2, 0)   (1, 1.4, 1)
2015-11-27   (4, 8.2, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-11-28           NaN   (1, 1.4, 1)
2015-11-29   (4, 8.2, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-11-30   (4, 8.2, 0)   (1, 1.4, 1)
```

---

```
# 'W-Sat' tells pandas to end weeks on Saturday.
df.stack().groupby(
    [pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='W-Sat'), pd.Grouper(level=1)]
).apply(lambda s: s.value_counts().idxmax()).unstack()

                     One           Two
Date                                  
2015-11-21  (3, 10.0, 0)          None
2015-11-28   (4, 8.2, 0)   (1, 1.4, 1)
2015-12-05   (4, 8.2, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
```

---

Another way to have done this would be to stack it first and manipulate level values

```
ds = df.stack()
g1 = (ds.index.get_level_values(0) - ds.index.levels[0].min()).days // 7
g2 = ds.index.get_level_values(1)
ds.groupby([g1, g2]).apply(lambda s: s.value_counts().idxmax()).unstack()

            One           Two
0  (3, 10.0, 0)          None
1   (4, 8.2, 0)   (1, 1.4, 1)
2   (4, 8.2, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
```

---

In the event you have `np.nan` that span an entire week and you want to return `np.nan` for those weeks, we need to tell `stack` not to `dropna` and pass a function to `apply` that can handle those `np.nan`

```
def value_counts_idxmax(s):
    try:
        return s.value_counts().idxmax()
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

df.stack(dropna=False).groupby(
    [pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='W-Sat'), pd.Grouper(level=1)]
).apply(value_counts_idxmax).unstack()


           3046920017503 3046920017541
index                                 
2015-11-21           NaN           NaN
2015-11-28           NaN           NaN
2015-12-05  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
2015-12-12  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
```

Or with the second method

```
ds = df.stack(dropna=False)
g1 = (ds.index.get_level_values(0) - ds.index.levels[0].min()).days // 7
g2 = ds.index.get_level_values(1)
ds.groupby([g1, g2]).apply(value_counts_idxmax).unstack()

  3046920017503 3046920017541
0           NaN           NaN
1           NaN           NaN
2  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
3  (3, 10.0, 0)  (3, 10.0, 0)
```

Comment: That looks great, many thanks. Just wondering, why are there the last two rows in your output dataframe? In my mind, the index of the output table should stand for the first day in the week for which it gives the most frequent occurrence.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, especially with the amendment to allow for the week to end at a custom choice day of the week.

Comment: I am using your method with a dataframe consisting of only ruples and nans, which has data for all days for some number of weeks. But the output data has a lower number of weeks in it. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Thank you kindly. Just wanted to let you know that the first method is significantly faster than the second one.

Comment: Minor comment: the suggested solution gives a dataframe with the wrong index (it is one week later than it should be (but that is no problem to change)

Comment: @splinter when using the `freq` option in the `Grouper` it will give the last date as the key.  If you can change it, great!  But out of curiosity, I'll take a look as well

Comment: I see. Perhaps there is an option in the `Grouper`. Otherwise, t's not a disaster because we can just do `df.index-datetime.timedelta(6)`. But anyhow, it's not a big deal for me. Just wanted to mention it for completion.